# Поиск кода в "модуле" CLion

Tags: c++, intellij-idea, ide, clion, jetbrains

Что означает `Module` в `Find in files/Find in Path` окне `CLion`? Как добавить или поменять модуль? Нашёл [документацию](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html) для `IDEA`, но не для `CLion`, в нём таких меню нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/2021.3/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html#find_in_project

Comment: Судя по списку модулей, это модули в терминах cmake.

Comment: @user7860670 мб там баг какой-то, потому что в некоторых проектах, где просто 1 cmake project с 1 таргетом-бинарём, почему-то в Modules показывает помимо этого проекта ещё и его же с постфиксом `_2`. Даже если поменять название проекта/таргета, то названия этих модулей не меняются